# Grails: query or criteria against a string/value pairs map property

Tags: grails

Grails gives the possibility of creating simple string/value map properties section ["Maps of Objects", first paragraph](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps).

I was wondering, is there a way to later query the domain class (using Gorm dynamic finders, criterias or HQL) using the map property as part of the query (i.e adding a condition for the key X to have the value Y)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with it a bit and almost give up, I discovered the map syntax to (surprisingly) work in HQL. Assuming the class looks like:

```
class SomeClass {
   Map pairKeyProperty
}
```

You can build queries that look like the following:

```
select * from SomeClass sc where sc.pairKeyProperty['someKey'] = 'someValue' and sc.pairKeyProperty['someOtherKey'] = 'someOtherValue'
```

Pretty neat! I still would prefer to use criterias as they are much cleaner to compose, but they seem to not support the same syntax (or I couldn't find it).

I created a sample app in GitHub: 
https://github.com/deigote/grails-simple-map-of-string-value-pairs

It can be visisted at:
http://grails-map-of-string-pairs.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

The form above uses a cross join.  To enforce an inner join use

```
join sc.pairKeyProperty pk1 on index(pk1) = 'someKey'
where 'someValue' in elements(pk1)
```

Comment: Better to use "member of" rather than "elements:"
    join sc.pairKeyProperty pk1 on index(pk1) = 'someKey'
   where 'someValue' member of pk1

Does anyone know how to enforce an inner join and still have comparison operators ("like", "ilike") instead of just membership tests?

Comment: Hey jphiloon, thanks for the answer! I was wondering if there's any performance difference between the two joins when the cross join uses the "where" properly - my last understanding is that there's not, but maybe I'm wrong.